# How to connect a MySQL database to a domain in iPage?

Tags: php, mysql, database, dns

I exported my database from PHP my admin and imported it to a database I created in iPage. I made a subdomain so I could upload the Wordpress Site for test purposes first. However, I'm not sure how to proceed and connect the two.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already created the database in the vDeck and assigned a database username to it, just edit the wp-config.php file of your Wordpress site.
There are 4 values you need to update:

> define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here’);
>
> /** MySQL database username */
>
> define('DB_USER', 'username_here’);
>
> /** MySQL database password */
>
> define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here’);
>
> /** MySQL hostname */
>
> define('DB_HOST', 'localhost’);

Please use the info you used when creating the database and fill in database name, username and password and for host use the hostname/IP shown in vDeck for the database.

Comment: Thank you Malin! Where can I find my hostname?

Comment: Okay, I changed the db name, user and password to match the info i used when I created the db. I left the db_host as localhost and saved the file. When i went to the subdomain, I got this message "Forbidden, You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Comment: You’re welcome. That’s because your file and folder permissions are incorrect. They have a tutorial here: https://www.ipage.com/support/tutorials/view_tutorial.bml?kbid=7433. Please make sure that your files/directories are all readable. Files should have permissions 0644 and directories 0755 for the site to be accessible.

Comment: Thank you for providing the tutorial. I went to go change the permissions for the directory but it already had 755 as the permission. I don't see any files in the directory, should I?

Comment: Yes, you should have files. Did you create the subdomain and upload the files there? Or you created the subdomain but uploaded the files somewhere else?

Comment: I created the subdomain and created and imported the database. What files should I upload? The entire Wordpress site?